# Converting links to links

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have an jQuery ajax function which returns `data`.  This `data` contains text such as:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://www.consectetur.com adipiscing elit. Nam quis purus id nulla http://www.bibendum.com iaculis. Phasellus varius pellentesque libero, ac congue neque dignissim eu
```

How do I convert this too:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://www.consectetur.com">http://www.consectetur.com</a> adipiscing elit. Nam quis purus id nulla a href="http://www.bibendum.com">http://www.bibendum.com</a> iaculis. Phasellus varius pellentesque libero, ac congue neque dignissim eu
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stand back! I know regular expressions:

```
var anchored = myInputData.replace( /(http:\/\/[^\s]{5,})/g, 
                                    "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>")
```

(Globally replaces everything which starts with http:// and continues until there is whitespace with the pattern you describe)

Comment: Add s? so it also supports ssl.

Comment: That works nicely, but not with I add it to the rest of my script.  So I'll accept this answer and start a new question shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex matches to find "http://...... " and add the anchor stuff around it.

Excellent reference for javascript regex is [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)